# upload live audio from recorder as chunk stream in multipart message to a http/2 endpoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, nsurlsession

How to upload live audio from recorder as chunk stream in multipart message to a http/2 endpoint using urlsession. I am chunking the audio from the recorder say 320 bytes from buffer. I have been trying input and output stream pair but couldn't achieve. Please point me in right direction.

Note : This is for AVS (Alexa Voice services)
AVS document quote : **"The request sent to AVS is a multipart message: the first part a JSON-formatted object, the second part binary audio captured by the microphone. We encourage streaming (chunking) captured audio to the Alexa Voice Service to reduce latency; the stream should contain 10ms of captured audio per chunk (320 bytes).**"
Thanks

Comment: you can use https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire to achieve this

Comment: @Dilip, did you figure out a solution for this?